# Castle Interface Proxy without target

Tags: c#, castle-dynamicproxy

I am trying to create a Proxy for an interface without a target and I always get a `System.NullReferenceException` when I invoke a method on the resulting proxy, although, the *interceptor* is always well invoked.

Here it is the definition for the interface and the interceptor:

```
internal class MyInterceptor : IInterceptor
{
    public void Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
    {
            Console.WriteLine(invocation.Method.Name);
    }
}

public interface IMyInterface
{
    int Calc(int x, int y);
    int Calc(int x, int y, int z);
}
```

And here it is the Main program:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ProxyGenerator generator = new ProxyGenerator();

        IMyInterface proxy = (IMyInterface) generator.CreateInterfaceProxyWithoutTarget(
            typeof(IMyInterface), new MyInterceptor());

        proxy.Calc(5, 7);
    }
}
```

The interceptor is invoked but I get an exception from the DynamicProxyGenAssembly2. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the return type of the `Calc` method that is a primitive `Int32`. Once you are not specifying the returned value in your interceptor then it will return `null` and thus, when the proxy tries to convert that value to `Int32` it will throw a `NullPointerException`.

To fix the problem you should set the return value in the `intercept`method, e.g. `invocation.ReturnValue = 0;`